# subtraction of a minimum value within an array in a list

Tags: list, python-2.7, subtraction

Suppose I have a list

```
x = [[1,2,3],[5,4,20],[9,100,7]]
```

I want to something similar to:

```
xcor = x - min(x) #should return [[0,1,2],[1,0,16],[2,93,0]]
```

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: Sorry forgot to specify python for tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[y-m for y in q] for (q,m) in [[q,min(q)] for q in x]]
```

Comment: This works the best for the sample array given. The actually array I'm working has x = [[[1, 2, 3]], [[5, 4, 20]], [[9, 100, 7]]]. Is there any way to modify your code for such a list?

Comment: [[[y-m for y in q]] for (q,m) in [[q[0],min(q[0])] for q in x]]

Answer (score 0):

Well try exactly what you say.

Find the minimum value first and either edit the existing list or create a new array.

Something like this for the minimum:

```
def min_value(x):
    min = x[0]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] < min:
            min = cell
    return min
```

and either something this

```
def subtract_min_from_each_list(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        min = min_value(x[i])
        for j in range(len(x[i])):
            x[i][j] = x[i][j] - min
    return x
```

or this

```
def get_subtracted_list(x):
    new_x = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        temp = []
        min = min_value(x[i])
        for j in range(len(x[i])):
            temp.append(x[i][j] - min)
        new_x.append(temp)
    return new_x
```

to act on your list.

Answer (score 0):

you can try following in python

```
x = [[1,2,3], [5,4,20], [9,100,7]]

for n in range(len(x)):
    pivot = x[n][n]
    for m in range(len(x[0])):
        x[n][m] = x[n][m] - pivot

print x
```